# SAX Parser issue NullPointer

Tags: android, sax

All, the following code is throwing an NullPointerException.

```
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser(); 

        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader(); 

        dataHandler dataHandler = new dataHandler(); 
        xr.setContentHandler(dataHandler); 

xmldata="<ArrayOfNacionalClass xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceCompras" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Batata Congelada Pré Frita Perdigão 400g</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>2,50</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Iogurte Polpa Morango Batavo 540g</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>2,20</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Protetor Solar Loção FPS 15 Sundown 120ml</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>16,83</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Costela Bovina Resfriada por kg com Peso Aprox. 1,250 Kg</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>10,87</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Refrigerante Pepsi 2 Litros</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>2,99</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Pizza Mussarela Ristorante 340g</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>5,98</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Néctar de Uva Del Valle Mais 1,5L</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>4,99</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Batata Original Ruffles 400g</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>11,70</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Bolo de Chocolate Granulado por kg com Peso Aprox. 0,500 Kg</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>14,00</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Sorvete Especial Diamante Negro Kibon 2L</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>15,38</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Bebida Láctea Nescau Fast Nestlé 300ml</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>2,38</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Cerveja Pilsen Nova Schin 473ml</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>1,69</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Lava Roupas Líquido Concentrado Omo Multiação 315ml</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>5,20</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Kit Shampoo e Condicionador Controle de Queda 400ml Pantene Pro-V</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>17,00</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass><NacionalClass><ProdutoName>Amaciante Comfort Original 500ml</ProdutoName><ProdutoPreco>5,00</ProdutoPreco></NacionalClass></ArrayOfNacionalClass>"

InputSource is=new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmldata.getBytes()));



try {
      xr.parse(is);
  }catch (Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I honestly dont understand why its giving me NullPointer Exception, I also tried usind stringreader instead of ByteArray with NO luck

Please help..thanks

Comment: `dataHandler dataHandler = new dataHandler(); ` does not make any sense. This would never compile. Classes start with a capital letter. Could you also post the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: 10-31 21:29:44.043: WARN/System.err(364): org.xml.sax.SAXException: No input specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used a SAXParser I found that I needed to add the XML header to my file before it would work, and I also needed to enclose all my data in a single top level tag, e.g.

```
  private static final String XML_HEADER = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><z>";
  private static final String XML_FOOTER = "</z>"

  String xmldata = XML_HEADER + 
                   "<ArrayOfNacionalClass ... your data >" +
                   XML_FOOTER;
  sp.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmldata.getBytes("UTF-8")), 
           this);
```

You might not need the `<z></z>` parts above if all your data will always be enclosed in your top level `ArrayOfNacionalClass` tag.

```
<ArrayOfNacionalClass>your data</ArrayOfNacionalClass>
```

If you leave my `<z></z>` tags in then you'll need to handle them in your DefaultHandler class.

In case none of that helps, here's some sample code for a SAXParser that you might find useful:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

The code you've posted doesn't look like it will compile, unless this is your own dataHandler class?  If that's the case then you should post the code for that too.

I recommend you use an IDE that will help you fix compile errors as you type (e.g. Eclipse).

Comment: Actually datahandler is a class that extends DefaultHandler, and it does compile, I changed the name to avoid confusion

Comment: I am still getting NullPointer....at first I thought that my XML is malformed, but it isnt, and if I inspect the InputSource variable I get null for SystemID and PublicID. Interestingly enough the ByteStream property has all the data.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion in my updated answer above?  Definitely start with very simple data first!

Comment: Actually the issue was in the datahandler class. I fixed and then the class got populated with the xml data. Thanks